# Autocad startup LISP code broken after network reset

Tags: networking, autocad, lisp

I have a network with a few different drives on it with AutoCAD installed on my local.

I have a startup LISP routine for AutoCAD that loads a variety of other .lsp files, which are called by custom commands in AutoCAD, located in various drives across the network.

Up until yesterday it all worked fine, no errors, always loaded all the .lsp files. But after I reset a couple drives on the network the .lsp files located in those drives are no longer being recognized.

Nothing has changed programmatically. I've re-added all the network locations to the "Trusted" and "Support File" paths in AutoCAD's options and made sure the startup LISP is loaded in the APPLOAD menu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the **Startup Suite** as part of the `APPLOAD` command dialog to automatically load your 'Startup' LISP program (which then subsequently loads other program files), I would instead  suggest using the `acaddoc.lsp` file to automatically load your programs, as this is a far more reliable loading method.

To load programs using the `acaddoc.lsp`, perform the following procedure:

1. Check whether or not an `acaddoc.lsp` already exists. To do this, open AutoCAD to a new blank drawing, and type at the AutoCAD command-line:

   ```
   (findfile "acaddoc.lsp")
   ```

   - If this returns a valid filepath, in the steps that follow, navigate to the filepath and open & modify the existing `acaddoc.lsp` using Windows Notepad or other plain text editor.
   - If the above expression returns `nil`, open Windows Notepad (or other plain text/code editor), and create a new `acaddoc.lsp` in a Trusted AutoCAD Support File Search Path.
2. On a new line in the `acaddoc.lsp`, enter the desired `load` or `autoload` expressions to load your custom programs, e.g.:

   ```lisp
   (load "MyProgram.lsp" "MyProgram.lsp failed to load.")
   ```

   ```lisp
   (autoload "MyProgram.lsp" '("MyCommand"))
   ```
3. Save the new/modified file and open a new drawing in AutoCAD to automatically load it.

---

### Some Background on the `acaddoc.lsp` File

To provide a little background information on the nature and behaviour of the `acaddoc.lsp` file in AutoCAD: when opening a drawing, AutoCAD will search the Working Directory (that is, the directory in which the active drawing resides), and all Support File Search Paths (those listed in the `Files` tab of the `Options` dialog) for a file with the filename `acaddoc.lsp`.

In more recent AutoCAD releases in which the `SECURELOAD` system variable is present, only paths which are also listed as Trusted Paths will be considered by this search<sup>1</sup>.

When such a file is found, AutoCAD will cease searching and will proceed to load the acaddoc.lsp file into the active drawing namespace.

The act of loading a LISP file simply means that the contents of the file are read and any LISP expressions found therein are evaluated by the LISP interpreter.

In this way, most users will utilise the `acaddoc.lsp` to automatically load custom programs when a drawing is opened, so that such programs are available during the drawing session. **This is a more reliable and ﻿migratable method than using the Startup Suite for the same purpose.**

---

### Similar Autoloading Files

Aside, note that the `acaddoc.lsp` is not the only file that is automatically sought and loaded into the active drawing...

When the AutoCAD application is initially opened, a number of files are automatically loaded and others are reloaded again when every drawing is opened thereafter.

Most of these files are part of the application itself and hence should not be modified, others however are reserved for user customisation and can be modified and created if they don't already exist.

Below is the loading order of the various files that are automatically loaded into AutoCAD, with a brief description about each item:

- **`acad.rx`**
  This file loads various ObjectARX applications when AutoCAD is started.
- **`acad20##.lsp`**
  This file loads the `acad20##doc.lsp` file in versions which do not load such file automatically. This file should **not** be modified.
- **`acad.lsp`**
  The loading of this file is dependent on the setting of the
  `ACADLSPASDOC` system variable:

  - `ACADLSPASDOC = 0` (default) Loads `acad.lsp` into just the first drawing opened in an AutoCAD session, and will not load for each subsequently opened drawing.
  - `ACADLSPASDOC = 1` Loads `acad.lsp` into every drawing opened.

  This file is reserved for user customisation and is intended to be used for application-specific startup routines, as all functions and variables defined in an
  `acad.lsp` file are only available in the first drawing.

  If functions are required in all drawings, rather than altering the value of
  `ACADLSPASDOC`, functions & programs should be moved from the `acad.lsp` file into the `acaddoc.lsp` file.
- **`acad20##doc.lsp`**
  This file is automatically loaded every time a drawing is opened and loads the `autoload` function definiton and other utility functions required by AutoCAD. This file should **not** be modified.
- **`acaddoc.lsp`**
  As described above, if found, this file is automatically loaded into every drawing opened in the AutoCAD session. This file is useful for loading a library of AutoLISP functions to be available every time a drawing is opened.

  The `acaddoc.lsp` file is always loaded with each drawing regardless of the settings of the `ACADLSPASDOC` system variable.

  Since AutoCAD will search the working directory before the Support File Search Paths and will load the first `acaddoc.lsp` file found, users can have a different `acaddoc.lsp` file in each drawing directory, which would load specific AutoLISP routines for certain types of drawings or jobs.<sup>2</sup>
- **`acad.dvb`**
  This file will automatically load VBA projects for versions in which VBA is enabled.
- **Main CUI/CUIX and related files**
  A `CUIx` file contains multiple XML based files and image files, each of which contains the data for a user interface element that can be customised. `CUIx` files replace the `CUI`, `MNU`, `MNS`, and `MNC` files that were used to define menus in previouse releases.

  The Main CUIx file defines the majority of interface elements in AutoCAD.
- **Enterprise CUI/CUIX and related files**
  The Enterprise `CUIx` file is typically controlled by a CAD manager and accessed by many users, usually from a shared network location.

  This file is read-only to users to prevent the data in the file from being changed. A CAD manager would create an enterprise `CUIx` file by modifying a Main `CUIx` file and then saving the file to a shared network location.
- **`acetmain.mnl`**
  This file loads the Express Tools menugroups.
- **Express Tools LISP & MNL files**
  The various LISP and Menu files required by the Express Tools programs are loaded here.
- **Startup Suite programs**
  Programs files residing in the Startup Suite are now loaded, in the order they appear in the `APPLOAD` dialog.

  As noted above, the Startup Suite is known to be temperamental in some versions of AutoCAD, so I would recommend using the `acaddoc.lsp` for loading functions and programs required during the drawing session.
- **`(S::STARTUP)`**
  This post-initialisation function can be utilised to perform operations after the drawing has initialised in the drawing editor.

  Since the `acad.lsp` and `acaddoc.lsp` files are loaded early in the drawing initialisation procedure, commands issued at run-time from these files may be unsuccessful as the command-line may not be initialised in the drawing.
- **`acad.exe` command-line switch `/b`**
  The command-line switch `/b` can be used to run a Script when the AutoCAD application is launched. Any Script operations called in this way will be executed after drawing initialisation has completed.

  Command-line switches can be set from within the properties of the AutoCAD application shortcut icon, within the Target edit box.

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> This was introduced to mitigate against AutoCAD 'viruses' in which a drawing file would be sent to a third-party along with an accompanying malicious `acaddoc.lsp` file residing in the same folder, such that when the drawing file was opened, AutoCAD would automatically evaluate the malicious `acaddoc.lsp` file.

<sup>2</sup> This is only possible if the `SECURELOAD` system variable is set to `0`.